# Js Node Selenium Try-Catch Js Error not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, try-catch

I'm trying to simulate clicking on an element that is rendered after a certain iteration of document.readyState='complete'. To get around the readyState issue, I thought of try-catching the executeScript command to just make it retry until it works.

But for some reason Node / Selenium just stops working entirely from the resulting Js error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parentElement')

Any ideas on how I should solve this? Here's part of my code. It'll open up the supplied url (item) and should execute the command as soon as the element icon-download is rendered.

```
async function getFileFromUrl(item) {
  var command = "document.getElementsByClassName('icon-download')[0].parentElement.click()";
  driver.get(item);
  do {
    await delay(500);
    try{
      driver.executeScript(command);
    } catch (e) {
      continue;
    }
    break;
  } while (true);
  await delay(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to fix it by prefixing the driver-commands with Await. If they return an exception it's recognized by Node now. Code below:

```
async function getFileFromUrl(item) {
  var command = "document.getElementsByClassName('icon-fpk icon-download-xls')[0].parentElement.click()";
  await driver.get(item);
  do {
    await delay(500);
    try{
      await driver.executeScript(command);
    } catch {
      continue;
    }
    break;
  } while (true);
  await delay(3500);
}
```